# How can I get MVC3 to call a view with a different name?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have the following in my controller:

```
    public ActionResult Tests()
    {
    }

    public ActionResult Test()
    { 
    }
```

I would like both to go to the Test.cshtml view when I return. Can someone tell me if this is possible. I know the Test one will by default go to Test.cshtml but what about Tests? How can I direct that to the Test.cshtml?

Alternatively should I keep these as two views and use RenderPartial? If I did that then how can I pass my Model into the RenderPartial view?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Provide view name when returning

It seems you haven't really checked out method overloads. When returning from controller actions there are [several possible overloads](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.aspx) that return `ViewResult` result. One of them allows you to provide view name:

```
public ActionResult Tests()
{
    ...
    // provide the model too if you need to
    return View("Test", model);
}

public ActionResult Test()
{ 
    ...
    // provide the model too if you need to
    return View("Test", model);
}
```

### Html.RenderPartial has overloads too

The same is true about `Html.RenderPartial` where you can also provide model while calling it. Check its extension methods [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.htmlhelper.aspx).

#### I suggest you check documentation because you'll understand much more.

Comment: Sorry. I am not sure because I use a viewmodel. Currently it is return View(test) and return View(tests).  How do I fit in what you suggest with a viewmodel? Thanks.

Comment: @DavidG: Check overloads as suggested and you'll see you can provide model along with it as well. I Edited my code.

Answer (score 1):

Use [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460352.aspx) Overload

```
return View("Test");
```

This will return view named "Test" despite of the calling action

Comment: and its best to always specify the name of the view so that when unit testing you can check it to make sure you're getting the expected view back from the controller.

Answer (score 1):

The overload of `View` allows you to explicitly name which view to use.

```
public ActionResult Tests()
{
  return View("Test");
 }

 public ActionResult Test()
 { 
   return View("Test");
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes just specify the view name:

```
return View("Test");
```

Comment: Sorry I didn't explain well. I use a ViewModel. It can be the same. How do I call both the view name and specify the viewmodel in the return? Thanks and sorry for not saying this in the question.